# Return value from modal dialog loaded page to parent page in .net using jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I was trying to to create a pop up page using jQuery UI Dialog which will load another .net page in the modal dialog. I was wondering how to return values to parent page when a link button in gridview is clicked on the modal dialog?

Answer (score 1):

If you can count on the page loaded in the modal dialog being served from the same domain as the parent page, then you can simply refer to a javascript function in the parent when a link is clicked like so:

```
$('.gridviewlink').click(function(){
    parent.someFunc(infoToPass);
});
```

If you cannot count on that, then you will have to use cross domain iframe communication techniques.  Here's a good article: [http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes.](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)

Comment: I will get this error when there is postback in the modal dialog...
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'theForm.__EVENTTARGET' is null or not an object"

Comment: Do you need a post back to occur?  I thought you just wanted to pass information to the parent upon link click.

Comment: I'm sorry...it's not postback...but the error occured when i clicked on the link button. Any ideas?

Comment: $('.gridviewlink').click(function(){
    parent.someFunc(infoToPass); return false;
});

Comment: That should prevent anything from happening when you click the link, except for the parent function being called.

Comment: It doesn't works! It stops on this....
"__doPostBack('gvComplainant$ctl08$lnkBtnComplainant','')"

Comment: Did you give the anchors rendered in the GridView a class of gridviewlink?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you! Actually, i don't really good in all this jQuery! Would you mind to create a simple project based on this situation? So, i can refer to it directly....

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to do that.  The anchor elements in the Grid view need to have this attribute, class='gridviewlink'